# All integer should be equal

Tags: function-construction

I have a list of 10 integers:

```
w={10, 20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85};
For[w;
[#1 == #2 == #3 == #4 == #5 == #6 == #7 == #8 == #9 == #10] & {10,
20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85},
w = w /. {x -> 
 Round[If[Abs[x - y] < 50, Mean[{x, y}], (x + y + 99)/2 - 99]], 
y -> Round[
  If[Abs[x - y] < 50, Mean[{x, y}],   (x    + y + 99)/2 - 99]]}, {x, 
 y} = RandomSample[w, 2]; Print[w]]
```

I always choose 2 random integers and compute their mean, then I replace the previous list with the recalculate integers and so on.  I to see if such an algorithm leads to a list in which all integers are equal, but unfortunately I cannot figure it out

Comment: This is extremely confusing.  Format your code so it is copyable.  Your title explains nothing.  Please think clearly about what you're seeking so we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: the syntax of the For function and of Function (&) seems completely incorrect. Refer to their respective documentation pages please.

Comment: Note for each iteration you are changing *every instance* of the selected integers. You should clarify if that's the intent ( some of the answers here are I think changing only one instance of each at a time .. )

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try to follow your code, but I think this is what you're asking for

```
w={10, 20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85};

replaceWithMean[x_] := Module[
    {pair,intMean},
    pair = RandomInteger[{1, Length@x}, {2}];(*2 Random positions in list*)
    intMean = Round[Mean[x[[pair]]],1]; (*Mean of selected numbers rounded to nearest 1*)
    ReplacePart[x ,Transpose@{pair} -> intMean]
];
allSame[x_]:=Total@Abs@Differences@x == 0;(*Test for all equal elements.*)
maxIt = 100; (*Max tries before timeout.*)
NestWhileList[replaceWithMean[#]&, w, !allSame[#]&,1,maxIt]
```

The NestWhileList will let you see the output at every iteration. If you only want the result after maxIt tries, replace NestWhileList with NestWhile.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. It shows the effect of diffusion which gradually smoothes an initially existing structure.

Here is a possible code. I think it is mainly self explanatory; hence only a few hints are given.

```
wlg = 15; (* length of the array *)

r := RandomInteger[{1, wlg}] (* a random position in the array *)

nn = 10^2; (* number of repetitions of the loop *)
```

Enter here to start another run

```
w = Array[Random[Integer, {1, 10}] &, 
  wlg] (* the array to be studied: random *)

(*
Out[214]= {2, 6, 6, 10, 4, 7, 8, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 10, 6}
*)
```

A possible different starting array would be

```
(* w=Range[wlg] *)
(*
Out[216]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
*)
```

Now the Loop, doing this
1) select two random positions p and q (not necessarily different)
2) calcualate their mean
3) make the mean an integer (I chose Round[]), call this "integer mean"
4) replace the numbers in the two positions p and q be the integer mean
5) Print the current Array w, prepending the sum of all elements of w

```
Do[
 p = r;
 q = r;
 m = (w[[p]] + w[[q]])/2
 mi = Round[m];
 w[[p]] = mi;
 w[[q]] = mi;
 Print[Plus @@ w, " ", w], {nn}]
```

During evaluation of In[217]:= 120 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,9,10,11,10,13,14,15}

During evaluation of In[217]:= 121 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,10,10,11,10,13,14,15}

...

During evaluation of In[217]:= 120 {8,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8}

During evaluation of In[217]:= 120 {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8}

Several modifications are possible

a) non random starting Array
b) another procedure to make the mean an integer
c) take real numbers instead of integers
d) take average of neighbouring Points instead of random ones
...

Answer (score 2):

For clarity I would suggest defining a function to create the new value from 2 integers.

```
newvalue[{x_, y_} /; Abs[x - y] < 50] := Round[Mean[{x, y}]]
newvalue[{x_, y_}] := Round[(x + y + 99)/2 - 99]

w = {10, 20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85};
n = Length[w];

While[! Equal @@ w,
  Pause[0.1];
  With[{p = RandomInteger[{1, n}, 2]}, w[[p]] = newvalue[w[[p]]]]
  ] ~Monitor~ w
```

Answer (score 2):

My take on the question:

```
w = {10, 20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85};

picks = RandomChoice[Range@Length@w, {1000, 2}];

iterations = 
  Reap[Do[If[(Sow[{w, pick, Max[Tally[w][[All, 2]]]}]; Equal @@ w), 
     Break[],
     If[Abs[Subtract @@ w[[pick]]] < 50, 
      w[[pick]] = Round[Mean[w[[pick]]]],
      w[[pick]] = Round[(99 + Tr@w[[pick]])/2 - 99]]], {pick, picks}];
    w];
```

I pre-pick pairs for convenience. `Iterations` ends up with the final result, and a list of each state, the picked pair for the state, and the maximal number of matching members. Nice for things like:

```
ListLinePlot[iterations[[2, 1]][[All, -1]], PlotRange -> All, 
 InterpolationOrder ->0]
```

[image]

Showing the approach to equality.

Better yet, a pack of them, over random integer lists of 100 length, e.g.:

```
packOfLines = Table[{w = RandomInteger[100, 100];
    picks = RandomChoice[Range@Length@w, {10000, 2}];
    Reap[Do[
      If[(Sow[{w, pick, Max[Tally[w][[All, 2]]]}]; Equal @@ w), 
       Break[],
       If[Abs[Subtract @@ w[[pick]]] < 50, 
        w[[pick]] = Round[Mean[w[[pick]]]],
        w[[pick]] = Round[(99 + Tr@w[[pick]])/2 - 99]]], {pick, 
       picks}]; w]},
   {10}];

ListLinePlot[packOfLines[[All, 1, 2, 1, All, -1]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
w = {10, 20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85};
While[Not[Equal @@ w],
  Print[w];
  {xi, yi} = RandomSample[Range[Length[w]], 2];(*Pick 2 different locations*)
  w[[{xi, yi}]] = Round[Mean[w[[{xi, yi}]]]];(*Replace both with the mean*)
];
Print[w]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mimicking the OP code, flipping every instance of the chosen values at each iteration..

You can set your chosen pair to anything you like and the procedure will result in all equal:

```
 w = {10, 20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85};
 NestWhile[# /. ((Table[#[[1, i]] -> #[[2]] , {i, 2}] ) &@ 
 { RandomChoice[#, 2] , RandomInteger[100]}) & ,
       w, (! Equal @@ Through@{Max, Min}@#) &]
```

> {44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44}

here is your function:

```
 w = {10, 20, 74, 77, 19, 79, 61, 67, 49, 85};
 NestWhile[# /. ((Table[#[[1, i]] -> #[[2]] , {i, 2}] ) &@ 
     { c = RandomChoice[#, 2] ,
       Round[If[Abs[Subtract @@ c] < 50, Mean@c, (Total@c + 99)/2 - 99]]}) & ,
       w, (! Equal @@ Through@{Max, Min}@#) &]
```

> {-10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10}